# Filepathes after .htaccess creation

Tags: php, .htaccess, relative-path

I have a **filepath** problem after the creation of a .htaccess protected **admin** directory. 
Here is the structure of the folder:
[image]

**file-controller4.php** was initially at the **root** of the directory next to **file-controller3.php** and **file-view4.php** was in the **view** directory. 
To call the **header.php** from **file-controller4.php** I use **set_include_path**.

The problem is that the **header** doesn't call the **css** file anymore which seems to be relative to the admin directory.

Here are the different files:

Admin folder:
file-controller4.php

```
    <?php

    set_include_path ( 'E:/xampp/htdocs/url/' );


    include '/view/header.php';
    include '/admin/file-view4.php';
```

file-view4.php

```
    <h1>This is a title</h1>
```

Root folder:

file-controller3.php

```
    <?php
    include '/view/header.php';
    include '/view/file-view3.php';
```

view folder:

file-view3.php

```
    <h1>This is a title</h1>
```

header.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <!--<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" />

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"></meta>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>

    <title>A TEST</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css-example.css" ></link>

    </head>
```

css folder:

css-example.css

```
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {
        background-color: white; 
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; 
        font-size: 100%;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 200%; 
        color: navy; 
        text-align: center;
    }
```

How could I load the CSS from file-controller4 like it does correctly with the file-controller3 ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You posted everything except the relevant part being the code inside `header.php`

Comment: Oups.. Thank you, I'ts now corrected.

Comment: To go up in a directory structure you need to use `..` So your code becomes `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/css-example.css" ></link>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in header.php  REQUEST_URI and detect where is script - in main folder or in admin. And then build url for CSS.

Like

```
 <?php
 if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "admin") !== false) {
   $css_prefix = "../";
 } else {
   $css_prefix = "";
 }
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo($css_prefix); ?>css/css-example.css" ></link>
```

But best and correct way is change logic of your application and move `file-controller3.php` inside folder `admin`

Comment: Ok, this works good on the header side. Dosent it give a possibility to modify the url direclty in the file-controller? The reason why I dont move all the controllers in the admin folder is because these controllers have to be accessible to people who are connected with a session but do not have acces to the admin page (file-controller4.php) which is protected  by the .htaccess in the admin folder.